# How to compare timestamp(6) columns with systimestamp in oracle

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I want to compare the timestamp columns values with the systimestamp value.
My table contains two columns from_date and to_date with datatype of timestamp(6). I want to check something like this

1. systimestamp between from_date and thru_date

Upon checking systimestamp is returning value with timezone but from_date and thru_date columns values are without timezone

select systimestamp from dual; -- 11/19/2016 03:35:55.042420000 PM **+08:00**

And from_date & thru_date like 08/03/2015 06:09:56.941255000 AM

Please advise me how can I achieve this comparison?
Can I use LOCALTIMESTAMP instead of SYSTIMESTAMP? or I have to use from_tz function on from_date and to_date columns before comparison?

Comment: Are these columns local times? If yes you can use LOCALTIMESTAMP.

Comment: No these columns contains the server time zone times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a comparison Oracle has to perform an implicit cast. I just made a test and Oracle runs internally

`systimestamp between CAST(from_date AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) and CAST(thru_date AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)`,

which is equivalent to

`systimestamp between FROM_TZ(from_date, SESSIONTIMEZONE) and FROM_TZ(thru_date, SESSIONTIMEZONE)`

In case your current `SESSIONTIMEZONE` is different from time zone of database server's operating system the query will return wrong result.

In order to get correct result you can use either of these expressions:

```
CAST(systimestamp AS TIMESTAMP) between from_date and thru_date

systimestamp between FROM_TZ(from_date, EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGION FROM SYSTIMESTAMP)) 
       and FROM_TZ(thru_date, EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGION FROM SYSTIMESTAMP))

systimestamp between FROM_TZ(from_date, TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR')) 
       and FROM_TZ(thru_date, TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR'))

systimestamp between FROM_TZ(from_date, TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZH:TZM')) 
       and FROM_TZ(thru_date, TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZH:TZM'))
```

`EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGION FROM SYSTIMESTAMP)` may fail, depending on your server settings.

Note, do not use `DBTIMEZONE` instead of `TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR')`. `DBTIMEZONE` can be different from time zone of database server's operating system. Time zone of `SYSTIMESTAMP` is given in time zone of database server's operating system not `DBTIMEZONE`!

Comment: Can you explain this point - EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGION FROM SYSTIMESTAMP) or TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR') may fail, depending on your server settings.

Comment: `TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR')` should work in any case. Usually time zone of operating system are given in UTC offset not as region (at least in our premises). `SELECT EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGION FROM SYSTIMESTAMP) FROM dual;` returns `UNKNOWN` which will not work, of course.